# cx_Oracle - DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, oracle, package

I have windows 7 64 bit OS with python 2.7.10 64 bit running and installed the Oracle Instant Client for 64 bit OS and as well as the cx_Oracle package for the 64 bit. I am getting the error like below

```
import cx_Oracle
```

ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Is there more information that is needed to address this question ?

Comment: If you are using anaconda, first install oracle instant client and then cx_Oracle. Ensure that all are of same bit.